# Get latest changes in time series data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

Please consider this structure:

```
Id       Year       Month         F1         F2         F3         F4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1        2020         1           A          B          1          2
1        2020         2           AA      
1        2020         3                      BB         11
2        2020         1                                 3          4
2        2020         2           F          G
```

I want to have this result:

```
Id       F1         F2         F3         F4
-----------------------------------------------
1        AA         BB         11         2
2        F          G          3          4
```

How can I have above result (get latest changes)?

Now I did it with a cursor and 4 variables and then I selected these variables. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Whats the actual logic behind your desired results?

Comment: Latest changes. Consider we have a page that get data from excel. In the first day, the user would upload the records. on the second day user wants to update `F2` and upload a excel file that `F1` and `F3` and `F4` have blank value and just `F2` has new value.

Comment: By latest changes you mean latest non-empty changes?

Comment: User just will upload latest changes not all fields. But I want to get the latest changes in just one record for every id.

Comment: @DaleK. Yes exactly.

Comment: And have you tried anything?

Comment: @DaleK. I did it in simplest way. I got 4 variables for storing non-empty latest value and in a cursor I checked all of these values and in the end I selected these variables.

Comment: `LAST_VALUE` with `IGNORE NULLS` came to mind, but you're on 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `FIRST_VALUE()` with the appropriate `OVER` clause is a possible solution:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT Id,
   F1 = FIRST_VALUE(F1) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY IIF(F1 IS NULL or F1 ='', 1, 0), Year DESC, Month DESC),
   F2 = FIRST_VALUE(F2) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY IIF(F2 IS NULL or F2 ='', 1, 0), Year DESC, Month DESC),
   F3 = FIRST_VALUE(F3) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY IIF(F3 IS NULL or F3 ='', 1, 0), Year DESC, Month DESC),
   F4 = FIRST_VALUE(F4) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY IIF(F4 IS NULL or F4 ='', 1, 0), Year DESC, Month DESC)
FROM Data
```

Answer (score 3):

This would work with any versions of SQL server:

```
  select id, f1, f2, f3, f4
  from (select distinct id from myTable) t
  outer apply (select top(1) F1 
               from myTable t1 
               where t.id = t1.id and f1 is not null 
               order by year desc, month desc) v1(f1)
  outer apply (select top(1) F2 
               from myTable t1 
               where t.id = t1.id and f2 is not null 
               order by year desc, month desc) v2(f2)
  outer apply (select top(1) F3
               from myTable t1 
               where t.id = t1.id and f3 is not null 
               order by year desc, month desc) v3(f3)
  outer apply (select top(1) F4 
               from myTable t1 
               where t.id = t1.id and f4 is not null 
               order by year desc, month desc) v4(f4);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RA2lCkzg)

Answer (score 1):

Using aggregate and re-parse

```
with t as(
select id
  ,string_agg(f1,'|')within group(order by year desc,month desc) f1s
  ,string_agg(f2,'|')within group(order by year desc,month desc) f2s
  ,string_agg(f3,'|')within group(order by year desc,month desc) f3s
  ,string_agg(f4,'|')within group(order by year desc,month desc) f4s
from myTable
group by id
)
select id
  ,case when charindex('|',f1s)>0 then left(f1s,charindex('|',f1s)-1) else f1s end f1
  ,case when charindex('|',f2s)>0 then left(f2s,charindex('|',f2s)-1) else f2s end f2
  ,cast(case when charindex('|',f3s)>0 then left(f3s,charindex('|',f3s)-1)
        else f3s end  as int) f3
  ,cast(case when charindex('|',f4s)>0 then left(f4s,charindex('|',f4s)-1)
        else f4s end as int) f4
from t
```

Upd1
Curious, on test table with 5000 rows (1000x[test data])

| variant | avgTime(ms) |
| --- | --- |
| first_value | 500 |
| select top 1 not null | 250 |
| string_agg - get first | 20 |

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't return the desire result.

Comment: Sorry. Everything goes right in my tests. for my understanding, on what data is the expected result not obtained?